# Integration Tests run indefinitely .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How to debug integration tests which are running forever without executing? There are a total of 45 tests and if I run these tests individually they run properly. I am new to .NET Core any clue or direction will be helpful.

This has started to happen after I updated my code to fetch secrets from Vault.

Comment: It is hard to tell but one of the reasons could be some kind of deadlock. But without a [mre] it is hard to tell.